# Random Forest application with 40+ Predictor Variables

Tags: machine-learning, classification, r, random-forest

I am using R package `randomForest` to build a Random Forest model for classification. Ultimately, I need to choose **one of five** programs for a group of individuals based on historical data. The final variable that is being predicted is a categorical "1, 2, 3, 4, or 5" variable.

I need to incorporate 30-40 variables--their importance will also be analyzed-- to reach a decision for each individual.

I have no problem training a model, initially. Below is a sample data set being trained with R's `randomForest` package. I am running up-to-date versions of both the package and RStudio.

```
set.seed(101)
train <- sample(1:nrow(Boston), 300)
Boston.rf <- randomForest(medv~., data = Boston, subset = train)
Boston.rf
```

*My question is*: Once I have a model trained, tested, and cross-validated, how do I actually apply new data to this model? Is it viable to use that many variables--**all categorical, some binary**--for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `randomForest` package supports various tasks using an existing `randomForest` object.

For instance, it offers the `predict` method which will perform prediction using a given trained forest and a given dataset. As an example, if you have a trained forest called `mod` and a dataset called `my_data`, predictions can be obtained by running `predict(object=mod,newdata=my_data)`.

It's worth reading through the package documentation which gives good examples of using the functionality.

I would note that any new data you supply to a trained forest object should have the same encodings and transformations as the data used to train the forest with.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Do you happen to know the difference between ```predict()``` and ```rfImpute()```? I feel more inclined to use ```rfImpute()``` as it remains in the ```randomForest``` package, but this is still a new topic to me. Thanks!

Comment: `rfImpute` and `predict` are two different applications. `rfImpute` _imputes_ missing data in the predictor variables (i.e. takes care of `Na` values in your dataset) while `predict` creates predictions of the target outcome using a (clean) dataset.

Comment: Both functions are "in" the `randomForest` package (I believe `R` masks certain functions depending on the packages read in, so will use the `randomForest` version rather than the base `stats` version). If you want to ensure that the predict function you use is in `randomForest`, you can use `randomForest::predict(object=mod,newdata=my_data)`.

Comment: That makes sense. Since the model is not imputing missing historical data, but rather making predictions based on historical data, would ```predict``` be more appropriate? Does it make a difference between ```predict``` and ```rfImpute``` if I am filling in "Person A is more likely to choose Program 1"? Also, I was able to unmask ```predict``` using : ```randomForest:::predict.randomForest()```. Thank you so much.

Comment: "More likely to choose" sounds like a prediction task, so `predict` would be more appropriate.